# Turn down Minecraft's anaglyph 3D?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

I'm a minecraft amateur and would love to play it in 3D anaglyph. The only problem is, I can feel  the strain on my eyes when I try to focus when I'm playing Minecraft in 3D.

Is there any way to turn down the 3D? I've searched for mods, but couldn't find any that could alter the intensity.

Comment: What do you mean, "hardcoded settings"? Do you mean making your own mod?

Comment: I mean changing the game's code, things you can't change in the settings menu of Minecraft. I may have chosen the wrong words to describe it.

Comment: Modding is certainly a way to do this (I'm fairly certain, the *only* way to do this), but how to create such a mod is a) off topic for Arqade, and b) if you're technical skills are sufficient to create it, your technical skills are more than sufficient to figure out what part of the code you need to change.

Comment: Once you find the code that handles the stereo separation, GameDev.SE might be helpful with any unfamiliar OpenGL details.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that I have knowledge of how to alter the game's code, or make a mod for that matter. I'm just an enthusiast who would like to get help with this 'problem'.

Comment: Oh. When you wrote that you weren't afraid of altering the code, I took that to mean that you could.

Comment: Well, I have the mental capacity to do so _;D_ , but I don't know where to look.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're asking then. Are you asking for instructions on how to make a mod that would do this?

Comment: Not a mod per se, but maybe someone knows of a way to achieve this without too much trouble. If it's do-able with help of a mod, I'll take that as an answer but I wont be able to make one or continue playing Minecraft in 3D.